# if $A$, $B$ and $A+B$ are nilpotent matrices over $\mathbb{F}$, then $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=0$ .

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$, $B$ and $A+B$ are nilpotent matrices over any field $\mathbb{F}$, then $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=0$.

I can only solve this problem when $\mathrm{char}\mathbb{F}\ne 2$.

Proof: Since $A$, $B$ and $A+B$ are nilpotent matrices, we have\[\mathrm{tr}(A^2)=\mathrm{tr}(B^2)=\mathrm{tr}\left((A+B)^2\right)=0,\]hence\[0=\mathrm{tr}\left((A+B)^2\right)=\mathrm{tr}(AB)+\mathrm{tr}(BA).\]Note that $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$, we get $2\mathrm{tr}(AB)=0$.

As $\mathrm{char}\mathbb{F}\ne 2$, thus $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=0$.

Comment: Is it true?Is it false? What did you do?

Comment: @Avitus It's true, I can only solve this problem when charF≠2.

Comment: Is the statement on your reference valid for all char's?

Comment: @Avitus My friend told me this and he said it's true.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks.

Comment: I could not understand why would trace of $A^2$ would be zero? are you assuming $A^2=0$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik If a matrix is nilpotent, then all the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, including trace and determinant, are zero.  If $A$ is nilpotent, then so is $A^2$.

Comment: @aron : Ok. ok.. I got it... $A$ is nilpotent so is $A^2$.. As $A^2$ is nilpotent... Trace of $A^2$ is zero... fine fine... I like this :)

Comment: @user1551 Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See lemma 4 and its proof in C. de Seguins Pazzis (2013), [*On Gerstenhaber’s theorem for spaces of nilpotent matrices over a skew field*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.4951.pdf).